# How to use a library in other c++ code?

Tags: c++, include-path

I'm trying to use a library  in my code. 
But as I'm new in `c++`, I couldn't do that without any errors.
First I copied library in my main file and then in my main code I just included `.h` files. 
When I ran it, it gave me some errors like:

> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl library"

The library contains `.cpp` and `.h` files of functions.
I'm doing it in Visual Studio 2012.
What should I do to use this lib?

Comment: I actually haven't used this library, but may be it has some `README` files which could help you with installation?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using [this](https://github.com/andrewssobral/bgslibrary) library, The documentation to make an installation on Visual Studio is located [here](https://github.com/andrewssobral/bgslibrary/blob/master/README_VISUAL_STUDIO_USERS.txt).

If this is your first time with C++ then this is a very complex project to start with... Using a library is a complex process as every single one has a diferent installation method.

Comment: when we have .cpp and .h files , is it different how to use them ?

Comment: They serve different purposes but its not obligatory. .h files usually hold the declaration of classes, structs and some types of variables, .ccp files hold the actual definition of this things. There is nothing to prevent you from not doing this. But it is actively discouraged.

Comment: thanks dear rlam12. I beg your pardon,but I have another question:). This lib has .h and .cpp files. is it possible just add these files like  .h and  .cpp files we can write by ourselves. Or using this lib is different?

Comment: Personally I haven't looked at the library in detail, but there are some libraries that support that (just copy the files) out of the box. But others need to be compiled as a DLL or a .lib file so that it is then linked to your project at compile time/runtime.

Comment: Thanks for your help.